# delete text without losing format of original message outlook vba

Tags: vba, outlook, macros

I need to delete some text before forwarding a mail, i am losing the formatting each time i do this. please see the code below.

```
Sub RemoveExpression()

Dim Insp As Inspector
Dim obj As Object
Dim subStr As String
Dim oMail As MailItem
Dim itmOld As MailItem, itmNew As MailItem
    Set Insp = Application.ActiveInspector
    Set oMail = Insp.CurrentItem

    lPosition = InStr(oMail.Body, "Subject: ") - 1
   '   obj.Subject = Mid(oMail.Subject, 5)
    subStr = Left(oMail.Body, lPosition)
    oMail.Body = Replace(oMail.Body, subStr, "")
    oMail.Subject = Replace(oMail.Subject, "FW:", "")

    'obj.Body = Replace(obj.HTMLBody, "abc", "")
    Set obj = Nothing
    Set Insp = Nothing
End Sub
```

how do i keep the formating and delete the text ?

Answer (score 1):

You are working with the plain text `Body` property. You need to read and set the `HTMLBody` property.